# Improved automatic pre-section page break determination

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, resume

I would like a particular section macro to automatically deploy a page-break directly above it, if and only if it would be placed too close to the bottom of a page. "Too close", here, means without enough room to typeset the section's first entry on its same page.

I use one of the below two environments to handle my sectioning, from the ["Medium Length Professional" CV's `resume.cls`](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv):

```
% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

\newenvironment{rSection*}[2]{ % 2 input arguments - section name and parenthetical
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  {\bf (#2)} % parenthetical
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

I would like to amend these to prevent the occurrence of the below-depicted issue, *without* any use of trivial `\pagebreak[N]` nor `\enlargethispage{k}` commands, which are not sufficient for most of my use-cases. I also do not wish to have to refactor my code to any more recent [ModernCV](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)–type class.

[image: An example of the described page-breaking issue.]

Please note that in the above image the small grey line denotes the present page break. In that example, the section entitled "International Collaboration Activities" ought be automatically moved to the next page, containing its first entry (`$C_{1}$`).

(N.B. I am hoping to avoid having to provide a MWE. I will provide one if nobody decides to make any suggestions after a few days.)

Comment: without a test document hard to say much but perhaps you can use the `needspace` package to test if the heading is near a page end.  Not directly related but I'll not that you are adding a lot of space tokens from  `<space>%` or ends of lines with no `%`, also `\bf` hasn't been defined by default in latex since 1993, so presumably you are defining it elsewhere in your class?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks so much for this suggestion! Those are great points, that I'd not sufficiently appreciated. I'm not defining those at all, to my knowledge. I presume the class itself does so (it appears to [compile on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/fbstmvfrdmnf), by default)? (I have no involvement in `resume.cls`—I'm just an end-user.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [David Carlisle's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) excellent suggestion to use [`needspace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) (of which I was previously unaware), I have solved this (for `rSection`).

The below patch suffices:

```
\patchcmd{\rSection}{\sectionskip}{\sectionskip \needspace{6em}}{}{}
```